# How to bind value to model from select

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Part of my view:

```
<form asp-action="AddEquipmentToExercise" method="post" class="m-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.ExerciseId">Title: <b>@Model.Exercise.Title</b></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.ExerciseId" value="@Model.ExerciseId" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.EquipmentId" class="control-label">Equipment</label>
            <select asp-for="@Model.EquipmentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.equipments">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Actions:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddEquipmentToExercise(int exerciseId)
{
    var exercise = repository.Exercises()
        .Select(ex => ex)
        .Where(exid => exid.ExerciseId == exerciseId)
        .FirstOrDefault();

    ExerciseEquipment ex = new ExerciseEquipment { Exercise = exercise, ExerciseId = exercise.ExerciseId };

    var equipments = repository.Equipments().Select(ex => ex.Title);
    ViewBag.equipments = new SelectList(equipments);
    return View(ex);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddEquipmentToExercise(ExerciseEquipment ex)
{
    repository.AddEquipmentToExercise(ex.ExerciseId, ex.EquipmentId);
    return View();
}
```

EquipmentId is always 0 (that is not correct)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xca1B.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to fix select list. Assuming that that your equipments have Id and Name properties, try this

```
ViewBag.equipments = new SelectList(equipments,"Id", "Name");
```